# .htaccess adding another Rule doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my htaccess which works perfectly

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^explore/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) renderpage.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2&subsubmenu=$3 [L]
```

but I need to add another one and so I added this `RewriteRule ^profiles/([0-9]+) profiles.php?id=$1 [L]`

and now my htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^explore/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) renderpage.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2&subsubmenu=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^profiles/([0-9]+) profiles.php?id=$1 [L]
```

but when I go to ex: `profiles/24` I get 404 error but with profiles.php?id=24 works normally, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the rules. That should work fine. But I do notice that you're using `profiles` and rewriting to `profiles.php`. So multiviews *might* be causing some funny business. Try turning that off.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
...
```